# AWS EKS - Only 2 pod can be launched - Too many pods error

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Each `t2.micro` node should be able to run 4 pods according to this [article](https://dev.to/wingkwong/how-to-fix-insufficient-pods-issue-when-deploying-to-amazon-eks-d35) and the command `kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep pods` output.

But I have two nodes and I can launch only 2 pods. 3rd pod gets stuck with the following error message.

Could it be the application using too much resource and as a result its not launching more pods? If that was the case it could indicate `Insufficient CPU or memory`.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  33s (x2 over 33s)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 Too many pods.
```

Comment: Pls add to the post `kubectl get po -A`, `kubectl describe node` output for better view what's going on in your cluster.

Comment: What kind of pods you are deploying there? On top on the previous  request can you please update your question with your pods yaml files?

Comment: Can't speak for deploying on EC2, but I had the same problem as OP when I tried to follow the EKSCTL tutorial on Amazon but with fargate. My fix: I had to create a new nodegroup for my cluster which then could house the nginx pods the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/sample-deployment.html site was asking me to create. The fargate nodes initially created by `eksctl create cluster` had  max pods of 1 each, which was already taken by other `kube-system` pods.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the AWS documentation [IP addresses per network interface per instance type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI) the `t2.micro` only has `2` Network Interfaces and `2` IPv4 addresses **per interface**. So you are right, only 4 IP addresses.

But EKS deploys `DaemonSets` for e.g. CoreDNS and kube-proxy, so some IP addresses **on each node** is already allocated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, turns out I didn't have my new namespace in my `eksctl` file.

```
fargateProfiles:
  - name: fp-core
    selectors:
      - namespace: default
      - namespace: kube-system
      - namespace: flux-system
  - name: fp-airflow
    selectors:
      - namespace: airflow
  - name: fp-airflow2
    selectors:
      - namespace: airflow2
```

Then to update live configuration, use this:

`eksctl create fargateprofile -f dev.yaml`