# cluster-autoscaler deployment fails with "1 Too many pods, 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector"

Tags: kubernetes, kops, aws-auto-scaling

I have created a k8s cluster with kops (1.21.4) on AWS and as per the [docs on autoscaler](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/addons/#cluster-autoscaler). I have done the required changes to my cluster but when the cluster starts, the cluster-autoscaler pod is unable to schedule on any node. When I describe the pod, I see the following:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  4m31s (x92 over 98m)  default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods, 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.
```

Looking at the deployment for cluster I see the following `podAntiAffinity`:

```
      affinity:                                                                 
        podAntiAffinity:                                                        
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:                      
          - podAffinityTerm:                                                    
              labelSelector:                                                    
                matchExpressions:                                               
                - key: app                                                      
                  operator: In                                                  
                  values:                                                       
                  - cluster-autoscaler                                          
              topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone                          
            weight: 100                                                         
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:                       
          - labelSelector:                                                      
              matchExpressions:                                                 
              - key: app                                                        
                operator: In                                                    
                values:                                                         
                - cluster-autoscaler                                            
            topologyKey: kubernetes.com/hostname
```

From this I understand that it want to prevent running pod on same node which already has cluster-autoscaler running. But that doesn't seem to justify the error seen in the pod status.

Edit: The pod for autoscaler has the following `nodeSelectors` and `tolerations`:

```
Node-Selectors:              node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
Tolerations:                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
```

So clearly, it should be able to schedule on master node too.

I am not sure what else do I need to do to make the pod up and running.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965832/aws-eks-only-2-pod-can-be-launched-too-many-pods-error). It can be related to the error you're having. You should understand why there's a `too many pods` error because it's about master node. Other nodes do not meet affinity which is expected

Comment: @moonkotte I am using t3.small instances and awsvpc for networking so it means I can have at max 3(network interface) *4 (ip addresses per network interface) = 12 ip addresses. But I can see in aws console that I have only network interfaces being assigned to the instance.  So I have not yet exhausted the network interfaces on master node. So assigning more pods should be possible.

Comment: But I can also see that there are 12 pods already running, and as per https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/tree/master#cni-configuration-variables, it suggests to use -max-pods equal to (ENIs × (the number of IPs per ENI - 1)) + 2, which equals (3*(4-1))+2 = 11 and as per https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/networking/aws-vpc/, it seems every pod gets an ip from vpc network. Nevertheless I will try to run more masters to see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: @moonkotte Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The problem was maximum ips that one could have with awsvpc for a given instance type. I have now switched to t3.medium instance and it works like a charm. Although it works but my question in comment above still stands.

Comment: @moonkotte If you could put it as an answer I can accept the answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer out of comments.

---

There are `podAffinity` rules in place so first thing to check is if any errors in scheduling are presented. Which is the case:

```
0/4 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods, 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.
```

Since there are 1 control plane (on which pod is supposed to be scheduled) and 3 worked nodes, that leads to the error `1 Too many pods` related to the control plane.

---

Since cluster is running in AWS, there's a known limitation about amount of `network interfaces` and `private IP addresses` per machine type - [IP addresses per network interface per instance type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI).

`t3.small` was used which has 3 interfaces and 4 IPs per interface = 12 in total which was not enough.

Scaling up to `t3.medium` resolved the issue.

---

Credits to [Jonas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64972286/15537201) about the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the pod/deployment for [**nodeSelector**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) property. Make sure that your desired nodes have this label.

Also, if you want to schedule pods on the master node, you must remove the taint first

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Comment: please see my edits in my question. I can see that the nodeSelector as well as tolerations are set to node-role.kubernetes.io/master, so ideally the pod should have got scheduled on master node.

Comment: Master mode generally has taints. Pls remove the taint using kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-

Comment: If I understand correctly then tolerations are actually to allow running pods on even tainted nodes. So I don't think just removing taint is sufficient. Moreover that will also allow running normal pods to masters, when I don't want them to run on masters at all.

Comment: BTW I tried that too and it didn't help.